# Why do the PendingIntents I create all carry the same extra?

Tags: android

I have this method which I call to schedule events in sequence

```
public void schedule(Event event) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context
            .getSharedPreferences("myapp", 4);
    int numberofintent = preferences.getInt("numberofintent", 0);
    AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    if (event.dtstart > today.getTimeInMillis() && event.isreminder) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, ReminderPopUp01.class);
        i.putExtra("id", Long.toString(event._id));
        i.setAction("com.blah.Action");
        Log.e("id in scheduler",Long.toString(event._id));
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                numberofintent, i, 0);
        mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, event.dtstart, pi);

        numberofintent++;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("numberofintent", numberofintent);
        editor.commit();

    }
```

But I get a strange result: the different PendingIntents at the different times are correctly scheduled,

**But they carry all the same extra "id"** !!! (but the id of each event is different)

Why is this happening?

---

EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT

**Please note the RequestCode is always different....**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android considers your Intents to be equal because they only differ in the extras. Intents are considered equals if their action, data, type, class, and categories are the same. To make sure that each intent is kept, you need to change one of those five things.

From the `PendingIntent` [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html):

> Because of this behavior, it is important to know when two Intents are considered to be the same for purposes of retrieving a PendingIntent. **A common mistake people make is to create multiple PendingIntent objects with Intents that only vary in their "extra" contents, expecting to get a different PendingIntent each time.** This does not happen. The parts of the Intent that are used for matching are the same ones defined by Intent.filterEquals. If you use two Intent objects that are equivalent as per Intent.filterEquals, then you will get the same PendingIntent for both of them.

Comment: thanks Brigam, I understand it, what could I change in this situation to make the intent different? As you see I change the request code, but the Activity i call is always the same... thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Three last paragraphs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

Comment: @JoseLUgia Jose isn't providing a different requestcode enough?

Comment: It depends. You can use the requestCode to identify an operation, you might want to keep the same requestCode. I'm guessing you want to perform the same action with different data. Why don't you try using PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT?

Answer (score 1):

PendingIntents are cached when the data you put in them is similar.
If you want to make sure the data gets overwritten and refreshed, just give a different parameter to it.